# What is this vignette coming from in my HDR compiled photo?

Tags: sony, hdr, sony-alpha, vignetting, samyang

[image]
**Compiled**

[image]
**±0**

[image]
**-3**

[image]
**+3**

Sony a6000 + Rokinon 12mm f2.0
Lightroom CC
Used Lightroom to do the compiling as well.

At first I wondered if it was coming from the lens hood, but I think I have other photos that I did not use the hood, that have this as well. Only in the compiled image though.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to Photo.SE. Can you edit your post to inline the images, rather than link to them? That way, if the link ever becomes invalid, this question doesn't point to a 404 page. Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any masking when producing the combined image? Via Layers? Via a brush?

Comment: It's worth highlighting it isn't really a vignette since it isn't fading.  It's more of an ovalish mask that got created somehow.  It certainly isn't present in the original images so it has something to do with the merge process

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely digitally applied, check your settings effects panel.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently, deghosting was set to high.